# How to add CSS behind text in Astra

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theme-astra

I'm new to Wordpress but I'm trying to create a green squint colored box behind a line of text. Just like in the demo website [here](https://wpastra.com/templates/fitness-trainer-04/) but using Gutenberg instead of Elementor.

[image: example]

It would be great if it could be re-used later on. What I tried so far was to follow the steps in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PL6Ks3uTsSs):

- Create a parallelogram [here](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/)
- In WordPress add the name "shapeone" to the `Cover` object in "Additional CSS classes"
- Click "Preview" in WordPress, then "Customize" and add the custom CSS from the shape in "Astra > Customizing > Additional CSS":

```
.shapeone {
    clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
}
```

This is the result:
[image: result]

How is it possible to add this green colored box behind the text? And make it move with the text and not cut of the text?

Comment: `clip-path` clips (as the name suggest) the text. Use an SVG as a background here.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with using pseudo-element before. Here is some sample code:

```
#banner { 
  position: relative;
}

#banner::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 1rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
  background-color: green;
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 100% 0%, 75% 100%, 0% 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

You can see it in action here - https://codepen.io/lukaszpiotrluczak/pen/mdKzrva

So to conclude:

1. to container element you need to add `position: relative`
2. you create `::before` element and give it `position: absolute`, `content: ""` and `z-index: -1`
3. you control position of this pseudoelement with `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom`
4. you give this pseudoelement `background-color` and `clip`

Of course there is a chance you will need to play with z-index etc.

If you provide link to page I can give you exact css to put.

Comment: Thanks but it needs to work in WordPress with the blocks and the Astra theme

Comment: I show you what css you need to add. I cannot give you exact solution if you don't provide url to site so that I can check what is the structure of your DOM.
What I provided is enough for someone who knows how html and css works. 
And I have checked it on WordPress with Astra at my solution can be used just needs to be adjusted

Comment: Hi @DarkLite1! Have you managed to do it? If not I can help you further